# How do you unit test if statements in angular

Tags: angular, function, unit-testing, if-statement, jasmine

I have a function that subscribes a response from the NGRX store then uses the variable provided to change a message.

How do I test that the message changes when the variable updates?

```
  getData() {
    this.service.getPreferences().subscribe(res => {
      this.mypreference$ = res.mypreference;
    });
    if (this.mypreference$ == false) {
      (this.mypreferenceType = 'noPreference');
    } else {
      (this.mypreferenceType = 'Preference');
    }
  }

getPreferences() { return this.store.select('user').map((state: User) => state); }
```

Comment: The first one I think your if statement cann't work, because you are outside of the subscribe. And can you post the code of getPreferences?

Comment: getPreferences() {
    return this.store.select('user').map((state: User) => state);
  }                                                                                              getPreferences returns the state from the NGRX store

Answer (score 0):

To do the kind of test you are looking for, you just need to stub the getPreferences method of your service. So something like this should test one of the paths in the function:

```
it('getData should set mypreferenceType to noPreference when getPreferences returns false', async(() => {
  let service = TestBed.get(Service);
  let component = TestBed.createComponent(Component).componentInstance;
  spyOn(service, 'getPreferences').and.returnValue(Observable.of(false));

  component.getData();

  expect(component.mypreferenceType).toEqual('noPreference');
}));
```

However as mickaelw said in a comment I'm pretty sure you'll find that the test will fail. The if statement will run before the code in the subscribe function.